# Login PHP doesn't select right user

Tags: php, sql

So, my problem is that I can't log in as any other user with my login script in PHP, it only selects the last row in the table.

```
<?php
require_once('core/config.php');
if(isset($_POST['lSubmit'])) {
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM cms_users");
    while($row = $result->fetch_object() ) {
        $username = $row->username;
        $password = $row->password;
        $id = $row->id;
        $Rank = $row->Rank;
        $fail = "";
    }
    if($_POST['username'] == $username && hash("SHA512", "SHA512", $_POST['password'] + "QxLUF1bgIAdeQX") == $password) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        header("Location: index.php?ID=$id&Username=$username");
    } else 
        header("Location: login.php?fail=true");
        $fail = "Username and/or password is wrong!";
   }
} else {
    header("Location: login.php");
    $fail = "Username and/or password is wrong!";
}
```

Comment: `+` is not a concatenation operator in PHP, it is an addition operator.  You need to be doing `$_POST['password'] . "QxLUF1bgIAdeQX"`.  This effectively wrecks all your hashes, since two non-numeric strings added together equal zero.

Comment: Of course it does, you are setting username and password on each iteration of the loop. They will always contain the last values returned by the DB query.

Comment: Your number of braces is uneven, you close one more than you open.

Comment: If you tabulated your code properly you'd see your missing an open brace after your else on the `If($_POST['username'] == $username`

Comment: Missing an opening brace for the first `else`

Comment: If you also used `+` instead of `.` when originally hashing your passwords for storage, they will all need to be rehashsed. In fact, you should look at your table's data, where you may find that all your hashes are the same!

Comment: Don't use `SHA512` for hashing, it's not secure enough. Look at `Bcrypt`. Also use different hashes for each password, generate new ones every time a new password is created.

Comment: Your code is flawed. You should be selecting the user from the DB where username = username and password = password. It doesn't really get much simpler than that.

Comment: Why are you selecting all users ->`SELECT * FROM cms_users`? Select only 1, using the `$_POST['username']` ->`$result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM cms_users WHERE \`username\`= ?"); $result->bind_param("s", $_POST['username']); $result-execute();`

Answer (score 0):

Your query select several rows :

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM cms_users");
```

You need to select the user in the table with the username and password passed. If a record will be fetch, that one is the user, otherwise it's a wrong login..

Answer (score 0):

Myabe you can try it like this:

```
<?php
require_once('core/config.php');
if(isset($_POST['lSubmit'])) {
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM cms_users where username='".$_POST['username']."'");
while($row = $result->fetch_object() ) {
    $username = $row->username;
    $password = $row->password;
    $id = $row->id;
    $Rank = $row->Rank;
    $fail = "";
}
if(hash("SHA512", "SHA512", $_POST['password'] . "QxLUF1bgIAdeQX") == $password) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
    header("Location: index.php?ID=$id&Username=$username");
} else 
    header("Location: login.php?fail=true");
    $fail = "Username and/or password is wrong!";
}
} else {
header("Location: login.php");
$fail = "Username and/or password is wrong!";
}
```

You should not select all users in your user table. Just the one match username is enough

Comment: This example is WIDE open to sql injection -> `"SELECT * FROM cms_users where username='".$_POST['username']."'"`. When using `mysqli` there is no reason to directly use user data in the query, when prepared statements can be used. php.net//manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php